# How do I solve coupled ordinary differential equations?

Tags: differential-equations

I have four coupled ODE's. I am not sure how to plot and solve them using Mathematica.

I won't give the exact problem, but the following is something analogous:

The equations

```
a= x'[t]
a'=-c1*x[t]/c2+c1*(y[t]-x[t])/c2
b=y'[t]
b'=-c1*(y[t]-x[t])/c2
```

Can be written as

```
x'[t]= -c1*x[t]/c2 + c1*(y[t]-x[t])/c2
y'[t]= -c1*(y[t]-x[t])/c2
```

The question is, now how do I use these in NDSolve to give solution and later a plot as well? I have initial conditions to plug in, but I am hung up on how to solve these coupled equations...

Thank you in advance.

*Edit* I do not know how to input this into NDSolve.

Comment: I think if $a=x'[t]$ then $a'=x''[t]$… and does `c1x[t]` lack a blank after `c1`? Your equation seems to be pretty normal, what difficulty do you have in solving them with `NDSolve`? I suggest you to give a more specific sample.

Comment: If $a=x'[t]$ then $a'=x''[t]$… have you checked the document for the syntax of `NDSolve`? : http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NDSolve.html?q=NDSolve&lang=en

Comment: No need to use NDSolve. This is a linear system analytically solvable in closed form with [DSolve](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DSolve.html) Please make an effort, look through examples there. There are [some almost identical to your case](http://wolfram.com/xid/0gitxu-bg8c32).

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
 2)[`Read the FAQs`](http://tinyurl.com/cacvex2)!  3) When you see good Q&A, vote them up by [`clicking 
the gray triangles`](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system 
is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.  ALSO, remember to 
accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, 
[`by clicking the checkmark sign`](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)`

Answer (score 12):

I liked the shaped of the solutions and couldn't stay away from posting this. No need to use NDSolve. This is a linear system analytically solvable in closed form with DSolve. DSolve can get you easily large formulas for general solution. But if you specify initial conditions you can get a bit more compact forms of closed solutions.

```
{X, Y} = {x, y} /. DSolve[{
      x'[t] == -c1*x[t]/c2 + c1*(y[t] - x[t])/c2,
      y'[t] == -c1*(y[t] - x[t])/c2, x[0] == 0, y[0] == 1},
     {x, y}, t] // FullSimplify // First
```

[image]

```
Manipulate[Plot[Evaluate[{X[t], Y[t]} /. {c1 -> a, c2 -> b}], {t, 0, 10}, 
  PlotRange -> {0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Thick, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}], 
  {{a, 1.3, "c1"}, 1, 3, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
  {{b, 2.5, "c2"}, 1, 3, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You may learn how to do that by looking into Help/Documentation Center/NDSolve/Basic examples 
and there example Nr. 3 gives the answer to your question.